# Accessing event attachment via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to get at calendar event attachments within google apps scripts? I realize that this is still a "google labs"-level feature, but getAttachments() would be really handy for some stuff I'm working on. Failing that, does the lab store its attachment data in a clever location (say, a tag containing a URL) that I could get at behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible as far as I know. As you've mentioned, it is a Calendar Labs feature. Many regular features are not available in Apps Script, so it is tough to expect this one. You can try opening a feature request though

Comment: Bummer. I figured as much. Thanks.